# Change element style on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, background

If you have the style like .

```
body { 
    background: url(img01.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

And you have the button like this

```
<div id='1'>
<input type='button' onclick="div_funkcija(1);" value="Answer"> 
</div>

<div id='2'>
<input type='button' onclick="div_funkcija(2);" value="Answer 2"> 
</div>
```

If u use this js function

```
function div_funkcija($div)
            {
                document.getElementById($div).style.display='none';
                document.getElementById($div+1).style.display='block';
            }
```

So on button click it hide the div1 and show the div2 .

How to make that div1 have the style body with this image as background "img01.jpg" and the div2 have the style body with the background image "img02.jpg"

Do you understand my question ?

Comment: `div_funkcija(2);"`  this is wrong syntax , you need to assign event like `onclick="div_funkcija(2);"`

Comment: @MaulikAnand accidently missed while typing but thanks anyways ..

Comment: `div_funkcija('2');` wrap Id by quotes, cause you are passing as a string, and also consider changing your ids that don't start with numbers

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EhHr4/

Javascript:

```
var d1, d2;

d1 = document.getElementById("1");
d2 = document.getElementById("2");

d1.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // toggle display
  d2.style.display = "block";
  d1.style.display = "none";        
});

d2.addEventListener("click", function() {
  d1.style.display = "block";
  d2.style.display = "none";
});

d1.setAttribute("class", "background1");
d2.setAttribute("class", "background2");
```

HTML:

```
<div id='1'>
  <input type='button' value="Answer"/>
</div>

<div id='2'>
  <input type='button' value="Answer 2"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.background1 {
   background: url(img01.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
}

.background2 {
   background: url(img01.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
}
```

For more help please provide more clarity in your question...

Comment: i have like 10 div's u think this is the best solution. Also i would love to set the background image for entire body .. Thanks for your answer

Comment: This is definitely not a perfect answer but it's hard really understand what you are asking for, feel free to tweak the above sample code, it's a good start. If you want to set the background-image for the entire body then just target the body element rather than any of the div elements and add the class name to your body element with the setAttribute function in javascript.

Comment: This helped me 'code' <input type='button' class="myButton"  onclick="div_funkcija(2); document.body.style.cssText+=';background-image: url(img01.jpg);background-repeat: no-repeat; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover;  background-size: cover;';" value="Answer">